# Linking ViewController to my code?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I created an Empty Application for the iOS and added a ViewController in which gives the following error while

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

None of the other google searches seem to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The single-view application template is almost empty, but contains the minimal essentials, like a MainStoryboard and view controller with just one view.

Answer (score 1):

If using storyboards, delete everything from didFinishLoading in the AddDelegate (except return yes;). Then in the build settings set default storyboard to your storyboard.  Add a view controller to your storyboard, make sure it has the white arrow on the side pointing to it.  That should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a view controller subclass and nib is not sufficient. You must actually instantiate your view controller in the app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. You'll probably want to use the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method to do so, and assign the resulting VC to the `rootViewController` property of the window created by the app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

All you may need to do if you are using storyboards is add one to the project and configure from there.

Answer (score -1):

Place the following code  within `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```